# What plant is this, is it a Hoya?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, succulents

[image: What plant is this?]

Just got this plant and I thought it's Hoya but not sure. Can anyone tell me the name of this plant please?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is [Cissus rotundifolia Vahl](http://florawww.eeb.uconn.edu/198500580.html)  also known as Arabian Wax Cissus:

[image: Top view of leaves]

[image: Side view showing stems]